# Connecting from .Net in SQL Server 2005 (Winforms)

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net, connection

I'm diong a typical Windows Integrated Connection from a .Net Winforms Application:

*Dim sqlConnetion As New SqlConnection("Server=jupiter;Database=io;Integrated Security=True;")
sqlConnetion.Open()*

I keep getting the following error:

*Cannot open database "io" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MARS\viking'.*

I've also tried the following connection string variations with the same results:

*Data Source=jupiter;Initial Catalog=io;Integrated Security=True;*

*Data Source=MSSGDEV;Initial Catalog=MSSQLSERVER;Integrated Security=SSPI;*

The wierd thing is I can connect to the db using the SQL Management Studio with the same user from the same computer using integrated security. Is there a bug in my connection code?  Or is there some special configuration setting on the SQL server I must set to allow connections from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker finally found the answer.  I'd put the sql server instance (there are two sql server instances on my server) in the slot where the database name belonged. . .  Thanks all for taking your time to help figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

Try "Data Source=jupiter;Initial Catalog=io;Integrated Security=True;" instead.  If you use Integrated Security, you have to use Data Source/Initial Catalog.  If you use Trusted_Connection, you can use Server/Database.  [ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#1) is fantastic.

Comment: Can you open that database with the login?  It seems to be failing on the DB, not the server itself.

Comment: That is correct.  That's what makes it wierd--I can connect to that DB, with the same user, etc using SQL Management studio no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edited my answer (since the question was updated):

You need to change "Integrated Security=True;" to "Integrated Security=SSPI" or "Trusted_Connection=True"

(note the underscore in "Trusted_Connection")

Comment: sorry, that was a typo.  It should have said:  Cannot open database "io" requested...